# Which class to predict for imbalanced data?

Tags: machine-learning, binary, classification, prediction

For machine learning binary classification problems with imbalanced classes, does it matter which class is considered the positive class? So if class A is the majority class, by convention do I want to predict that or the minority class (class B)? Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it does not matter, but it depends on your underlying problem. For example if you want to classifiy a medical test, where positive corresponds to 'disease is present' and we assume that positive samples are the minority, you probably want to predict how high is the probabilty that one Person is sick / belongs to the minority.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What about a situation where it isn't a clear yes or no (eg.disease is present/not present, make/miss a shot, healthy/not healthy). I don't necessarily have an example in mind, but what about the case where there isn't that hierarchy or structure in place, where it's just group A and group B -- do you tend to go with the majority class then?

Comment: In cases were you have just group A and group B, it is totally up to you. In general the minority class is harder to predict and therefore is more interessting. I would recommend you read the paper "Learning from imbalanced data" from He et al. (2009), it gives a good insight about this topic.